# Tensorflow LSTM memory usage

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm trying `LSTM` sequence labeling. Before add embedding layer I put input data directly to `LSTM` layer. But it gives me GPU memory error even if batch size is 1.

`max_length` is 330, should I have to change model or adding embedding layer will work? I'm using Titan X GPU with 12 GB RAM.

```
# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length, num_table])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length, n_classes])
seqlen = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None])

# Define weights
weights = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

def LSTM(x, seqlen, weights, biases):
    # given input: (batch_size, n_step, feature_table )
    # required : (n_step, batch_size, feature_table )
    x = tf.unpack(tf.transpose(x,perm=[1,0,2]))

    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_hidden)
    #lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell,keep_prob)

    outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(cell=lstm_cell,
        dtype=tf.float32,
        sequence_length=seqlen,
        inputs=x)

    # convert to (n_step, batch_size, n_classes)    
    temp = [tf.matmul(output,weights['out']) + biases['out'] for output in outputs]

    # convert to (batch_size, n_step, n_classes)
    temp = tf.transpose(tf.pack(temp),perm = [1,0,2])
    return temp
```

Comment: how many classes?

Comment: `n_classes` is only 2 but `num_table` is pretty large, about 50000

Comment: Are you building from source? Can you check what goes in and out of [the allocator](http://google3/third_party/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.h?l=59)?

Comment: Actually, you might be able to set `tf.logging.verbosity(1)` and see messages with `__LOG_MEMORY__`.